# 「口が X になる」: Craving for food?

Tags: manga, phrases

In this picture below (I snipped it from the digital copy I bought online,  兄の嫁と暮らしています) there is this phrase "もう口がアイスになっちゃった". An obvious reading is that she's really craving for ice cream. However, this is really an interpretation than translation. What is the syntax/grammatical explanation for this use? I assume it's of the form "口が＿＿＿になる" which is not obvious to me that it should be read this way.

[image: From the digital copy I bought online, 兄の嫁と暮らしています]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is spot-on.

> 「口{くち}が + [food item] + になる」

is an idiomatic expression that means a person is thinking about a particular food item so intensively that ***in his/her imagination***, s/he feels as if his/her mouth were actually stuffed with that food item.

For that reason (← unintentional occurance), the verb 「なる」 is very often used in conjunction with 「しまう」 as in 「なってしまう」、「なっちゃう」、「なっちゃった」, etc. in real life.

(Right now, I am murmuring to myself 「口がうどんになっちゃった！」 after having answered a question about udon broth.)

Look here for [some real-life example sentences](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/search;_ylt=A2Ri8cE7mj5d0B0AcK6JBtF7?p=%E2%80%9D%E5%8F%A3%E3%81%8C%E7%84%BC%E8%82%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E2%80%9D&fr=top_ga1_sa&ei=UTF-8&aq=-1&oq=%22%E5%8F%A3%E3%81%8C%E7%84%BC%E8%82%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%22&at=&aa=&ai=AxG.JT6LQ5C9IoO9Koi4RA&ts=15383) with the food item being 焼肉{やきにく}, a popular Korean-style BBQ.

Comment: So the "になる" is no longer directly related to the usual meaning of なる (become)?

Comment: Figuratively, it is still related, if not literally, because your mouth cannot become the food item itself.  That is why I said it was an **idiomatic** expression.

Comment: I just wanted to mention this. https://youtu.be/LxYu_tac8Rg?t=108